# How arrays stores in memcache via php-function Memcache::set()?

Tags: php, memcached, serialization

Does it use php function serialize() or some internal function of memcache extension?
If it uses serialize(), then I can serialize my data myself with json_encode, for example. Will it be faster?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation of [**`Memcache::set`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php) says *(quoting)* :

> Strings and integers are stored as is,
> other types are stored serialized.

So I'm guessing it uses `serialize` internally ;-)

A good way to speed up the serialization/deserialization process would be to replace the internal default PHP serializer with something like [**igbinary**][2].

There are a couple of notes about that in theses slides presented by Ilia Alshanetsky a couple of weeks ago at the Forum PHP 2010 in Paris : [APC & Memcached the High Performance Duo](http://ilia.ws/files/Barcelona_APC_MEM2010.pdf)